# In which of his books did Bhaskara Raya say "kaulaat parataram nahi"?

Tags: tantra, sri-vidya, kaulam, bhaskararaya

In his texts the great Sri Vidya guru [Bhaskara raya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhaskararaya) says "***kaulAt parataram nAhi***". 
In association to the glory of kaula path.

In which text is it found?

What is its meaning and context?